# What are the possible meanings of 'hub' when it is included in the name of a website?

Tags: meaning

This is the definition of *hub*:

> 1. The central part of a wheel, rotating on or with the axle, and from
>    which the spokes radiate.
> 2. A place or thing that forms the effective
>    center of an activity, region, or network.

https://www.google.com/search?q=hub+definition

I was wondering what are the possible meaning of the word when it is included in the name of a website. Because it seems to me that any website can act as a 'hub' (a network/activity site).

(One example is [GitHub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GitHub)).

Comment: See the second definition.

Comment: As Zairja says, so GitHub is a hub for Git.

Comment: In the name of a website, *hub* means whatever the namer of the website wanted -- and could mean anything, or nothing at all. This question cannot be settled by recourse to facts and reasoning. Voting to close "not constructive".

Answer (score 3):

If nothing else, it's a *section* to do stuff. Stuff can be anything, really. A website can have many hubs such as a forum or news feed. Found [this image](http://www.raincastle.com/images/web_hub1.jpg) that describes it fairly well:

[image: Website]

So a hub describes a "facet" of some task that needs to be performed on that site.

Comment: but according to the definition, shouldn't it be the 'center'?

Comment: From my understanding of the word, the whole site could be considered a 'hub' to do all those things as well. That doesn't disqualify the meaning I gave though I don't believe. I see a 'hub' as simply a 'place' of gathering for a central purpose. Example: In networking, a 'hub' is basically a connection point between other hubs or computers, but sometimes people refer to the computer a 'hub'. I don't know, maybe I'm looking too deep into this.

Comment: @janoChen This seems like nitpicking. Simply looking at the visual, one can see the website *is* the "center", with various facets acting as "spokes". In the question, [GitHub](https://github.com/) is a center for projects that use Git revision control. It's self-explanatory. Likewise, [GrubHub](http://www.grubhub.com/) is a center for food (grub), where you can look at menus, order online, rate restaurants, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In your case the second definition applies. GitHub is a web based central repository, network or hub that uses the Git revision control system for hosting development projects. To better understand the concept here are a few examples:

> The kitchen was the hub of family life.(from Oxford dictionary)
>
> Chicago is a hub for many cities in the Midwest.
>
> English.SE is a hub for English enthusiasts.